# Wait for data to have loaded before [(ngModel)] is activated

Tags: html, angular

I have the following code in a component.html-file, that triggers an error:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject.ignoreHolidays">
    Ignore holidays
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ignoreHolidays')`

I assume, that `[(ngModel)]` tries to read the value of `ignoreHolidays` before it has been assigned a value.

My component.ts file has the following in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.add(this._ignoreHolidaysService.getIgnoreHolidaysResult() //subs is subsink
      .subscribe((__ignoreHolidaysObject: IgnoreHolidaysViewModel) => {
        this.ignoreHolidaysObject = __ignoreHolidaysObject;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log("Call threw an error", error);
      })
    )
  }
```

All other values in my html-file are set and the call works as intended.

How do I ensure, that `this.ignoreHolidaysObject` has been assigned data, before `[(ngModel)]` tries to read from it?

Comment: Would a simple `[(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject?.ignoreHolidays"` solve the issue?

Comment: `How do I ensure, that this.ignoreHolidaysObject has been assigned data, before [(ngModel)] tries to read from it?` You remove the element from DOM with `*ngIf="ignoreHolidaysObject"`, typically you show a loading indicator while data from the API is still loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either instantiate `ignoreHolidaysObject` with some dummy data to allow the binding to be setup successfully prior to your asynchronous data arriving, e.g.

`.ts`

```
ignoreHolidaysObject = {
  ignoreHolidays: null  // choose a suitable "empty" value for your  use case
}
```

`.html`

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject.ignoreHolidays">
    Ignore holidays
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

or you can simply prevent the component from being rendered until your object has been populated and is thus ready to be bound

`.html`

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    *ngIf="ignoreHolidaysObject"
    [(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject.ignoreHolidays">
    Ignore holidays
</mat-slide-toggle>

or

<mat-slide-toggle
    *ngIf="ignoreHolidaysObject?.ignoreHolidays"
    [(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject.ignoreHolidays">
    Ignore holidays
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add ***ngIf="ignoreHolidaysObject"** to **mat-slide-toggle** :

```
<mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="ignoreHolidaysObject" [(ngModel)]="ignoreHolidaysObject.ignoreHolidays">
    Ignore holidays
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you! I wrote a comment earlier, that said this doesn't seem to work - that must have been a mistake on my part.